# ARM Assembly loading string produces weird terminal output

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, arm

I am trying to space out my string by replacing each character with a space string combined with an underscore string to create `_ _ _ _`.

However, I get a weird output:
[image: Terminal Output]

If I load 1 character e.g `ldr r1, = '_'`
it works however I get `_____` and I am trying to get `_ _ _ _ _`. What is the best way to do this?

NOTE: I do not know C and I am new to ARM.

My function:

```
sub r3, r0, #1 @has the length
    ldr r0, = buffer @has the word

    mov r5, #0 @start of increment
    mov r6, r0 @copies word to r6
loop:
     ldr r1, =spaceChar
     strb r1, [r6, r5]
     add r5, r5, #1
     cmp r3, r5
     bne loop
    mov r1,r6 
    ldr r0, = HiddenWord
    bl printf
    pop {r4,lr}
    bx lr
 
.data
 
    HiddenWord: 
        .asciz "Word: %s"
    spaceChar:
        .asciz " _"
    buffer:
        .space 100
```

Comment: You should really consult the documentation for at least the functions you try to use. `strcat` expects a string (as the name says) but you pass a char. That will fault.

Comment: I see, I just assumed it'd work on chars too as strings are just an array of chars. My bad, is there a way I can still achieve what I want?

Comment: @MazeMaster51 Make a two character string (the character you want and a NUL terminator) and place it in memory.  Pass the address of that string.  How did you expect `strcat` to know that the number you passed is a character and not the address of a string?

Comment: As I pointed out in previous comments, `strcat` and other library functions may overwrite `r0,r1,r2,r3`.  You cannot store data in those registers across a function call.  If you're going to call C functions, you have to understand the [calling conventions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0042/latest/).

Comment: Also your loop is not going to do what you want, and you don't even need `strcat`, you can just store the required number of "\t_" directly. Are you sure you even want a tab and not a space?

Comment: I see thank you for the guidance. @Jester I had previously tried to do it directly but the terminal only printed out YYYYYY for some weird reason. I stored spaceChar .asciz "\t_" in memory and then called it using ldr r1, =spaceChar then strb r1, [r6, r5]. It for some reason turned all the characters to "Y". I would prefer a space if that is easier, I assumed tab will be easier as it is denoted by /t.

Comment: Also `.byte 100` is declaring a single byte with value 100. You likely wanted `.space 100` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I get a weird output on the terminal once I made that change though. Can I not replace a character with a string?

Comment: You are storing the pointer, not the value. Also, 2 characters is a half-word. Anyway, since you already statically allocate the buffer the simplest solution is to preset it with " _" using your assembler and just put the terminating zero in the right place.

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions by removing all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already statically allocate the buffer the simplest solution is to preset it with " _" using your assembler and just put the terminating zero in the right place. I don't think you mentioned which assembler you use, the following works in gnu assembler:

```
    ldr r0, =buffer-1
    mov r1, #0
    strb r1, [r0, r3, lsl #1]

    ldr r0, =HiddenWord
    ldr r1, =buffer
    bl printf
    pop {r4,lr}
    bx lr
 
.data
 
    HiddenWord: 
        .asciz "Word: %s\n"
    buffer:
.rept 50
    .ascii "_ "
.endr
```

If you want to fill the buffer programmatically, that could look like:

```
    ldr r0, =buffer @has the word
    ldr r1, =0x205f @ underscore + space
loop:
    strh r1, [r0], #2
    subs r3, r3, #1
    bne loop
    mov r1, #0         @ replace final
    strb r1, [r0, #-1] @ space with zero
```